# Hard code a value into a data table

Tags: c#, datatable

How would I hard code a value into one the fields of a data table. This is what I have.

```
//create Data table to temporary storage

DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
protected void createTable(DataTable myTable)
    {


        myTable.Columns.Add("PilotID");
        myTable.Columns.Add("Start_date");
        myTable.Columns.Add("End_date");
        myTable.Columns.Add("Hours");
    }
```

Comment: Your code won't compile because of the var outside of a function. btw.

Comment: do u need to create this instance of `myTable` again n again?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) to set a column to a constant value.

For example:

```
// For a number
myTable.Columns["PilotID"].Expression = "1";
// For a string
myTable.Columns["PilotID"].Expression = "'MyPilot'";
```

Then every row that is added to the data table will have the same constant value in the column.  The DataRow will also throw an exception if some code tries to change the constant value.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

myTable.Columns.Add("PilotID");
myTable.Columns.Add("Start_date");
myTable.Columns.Add("End_date");
myTable.Columns.Add("Hours");

DataRow dr = myTable.NewRow();
dr["PilotID"] = 1;
myTable.Rows.Add(dr);

myTable.Rows[0]["PilotID"] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a globabl setting or class field to assign to a field of the table. Once you have your `NewRow()`, then:

```
myNewRow["ConstantField"] = Settings.SpecialValue;
```

**Update**

Using expression would be better as @shf301 suggests; however, I recommend using Settings to store your *hard-coded* value.

```
myTable.Columns["PilotID"].Expression = Settings.SpecialValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try it this way!

```
    string[] TABLE_COLUMNS = new string[] { "PilotID", "Start_date", "End_date", "Hours", };
    static void Main()
    {

        var i_need_new_table = HardCodedDataTable();
        var i_need_one_more_new_table = HardCodedDataTable(TABLE_COLUMNS);

    }

    private static DataTable HardCodedDataTable() // default hard-coded table
    {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        myTable.Columns.Add("PilotID");
        myTable.Columns.Add("Start_date");
        myTable.Columns.Add("End_date");
        myTable.Columns.Add("Hours");
        return myTable;
    }

    private static DataTable HardCodedDataTable(string[] columns) // table with predefined columns in array
    {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        Array.ForEach(columns, s => myTable.Columns.Add(s));
        return myTable;
    }
```